# React clear input field after submit form

Tags: reactjs, form-submit, submit-button

I want to clear the input field after upload and submit the form.

I have checked couple of documentation, where its said after submitting the form I can return the initial state.

**Here is my code**

```
 state = {
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: "",
    file: null
  };

  onDrop = e => {
    this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] });
    console.log({ file: e.target.files[0] });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };
  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.state.file);
    formData.append("upload_preset", process.env.REACT_APP_UPLOAD_PRESET);

    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUD_NAME}/image/upload`,
      formData
    );

    await this.props.addPerson({
      variables: {
        firstname: this.state.firstname,
        lastname: this.state.lastname,
        email: this.state.email,
        image: response.data.url
      },
      refetchQueries: [{ query: getperson }]
    });

    this.setState({ firstname: " ", lastname: "", email: " ", file: null }); **this is where i retutn the initial state after submitting the form, but it did not work**
  };
```

**This is my form setup**

```
  <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <form id="addPerson" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="field">
              <label> Firstname </label>
              <input type="text" id="firstname" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label> Lastname </label>
              <input type="text" id="lastname" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label> Email </label>
              <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.onDrop} />
            <button>Add Person</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: You haven't set the value with state for example - email, firstname and lastname. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Please check the answer and accept it, if it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because your inputs are not fully controlled by `react`, If you want to control these inputs, you need to specify the value attribute like this :

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" value={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
<input type="text" id="lastname" value={this.state.lastname} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

Note that the `file input` is always **uncontrolled** in react (see the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag)), so you need to reset it manually by using a reference :

```
 constructor() {
   this.fileRef = React.createRef();
   ...
 }

 handleSubmit = async e => {

   // Reset the file input
   this.fileRef.current.value = '';
 };

 render() {
   ...
   <input type="file" ref={this.fileRef} onChange={this.onDrop} />
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the `value` attribute in html input with state value.

Since the `value` attribute is set on our form element, the displayed `value` will always be `this.state.value`, making the React state the source of truth.

Since `handleChange` runs on every keystroke to update the React state, the displayed value will update as the user types.

With a controlled component, every state mutation will have an associated handler function. This makes it straightforward to modify or validate user input.

For more details please check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Use following code,

```
    <React.Fragment>
        <div>
        <form id="addPerson" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="field">
            <label> Firstname </label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" value={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="field">
            <label> Lastname </label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" value={this.state.lastname} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="field">
            <label> Email </label>
            <input type="email" id="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.onDrop} />
            <button>Add Person</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
```

Hope this will help you !!!